# AppstoreConnect: Company individual developer name instead of App description

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I was searching for a while and not found nothing...

I have an app published in iTunesConnect, but instead of the app **description** (**previously setted in AppstoreConnect**),
like in the image below:

[Subtitle demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVTxW.png)

... The owner account name (**individual account developer name**) is being presented.
Like this:

[App Store demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmbNq.jpg)

How i can change this to the appstoreconnect description text?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean. App description and account name are 2 different things. Sometimes screenshots can help the community to better help you.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing things up. By default the App Store displays two values:

a) **App title/name** at the top

b) **App subtitle** at the bottom

If there is no active app subtitle, the App Store falls back to the developer name. (Sometimes if the App Store is "slow", you will see the developer name for a couple of seconds, before it is replaced by the subtitle)

You can check the behaviour in this short video/gif I just made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYtES.jpg

The developer name is something you **cannot change** yourself in App Store Connect. It is the initial name you signed up with over at https://developer.apple.com/enroll

If you signed up as an **individual developer**, it will show your personal name.

If you signed up as a **company**, it will show the full company name.

You can change this, but need to contact Apple Developer Support for that: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/ They can also help you with upgrading your account from personal to company.

Comment: Wow... Now I've noticed, i think that i was always in a bad network, the developer name always appeared to me, but i tested in another iPhone and the description appeared. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yup, the App Store has a lot of strange behaviours, especially when it comes to "lazy loading".

Answer (score 0):

For ios 11 to onward enter subtitle it will display below app name.
Go to iTunes -> select app -> select app store -> app information -> enter subtitle

[image: Subtitle]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have a subtitle, but is showing the Developer Account Owner's name. I've updated the question with some pictures of the example.

Comment: what iOS you are using? subtitle will display in appStore for iOS 11 to onward. anything less will display account holder name.

Comment: My iOS version is 12.2